# Facebook Sharing SDK : Sharing UIImage to facebook

Tags: swift

I have a button in my app when tapped it calls this function to share a UIImage to facebook, but it doesn't work. I followed facebook's documentation and I don't know why it doesn't work.
This is my code

```
func shareImage(image: UIImage) {
    let photo = Photo(image: image!, userGenerated: true)
    let content = PhotoShareContent(photos: [photo])
    try! ShareDialog.show(from: self, content: content)
}
```

Can you please help me.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I've had success with this [link](https://medium.com/@h_shib8/share-contents-on-facebook-and-twitter-in-swift-3-slcomposeviewcontroller-fb02de241416) sharing content with Facebook.

```
let vc = SLComposeViewController(forServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook)
vc.add(image)
vc.add(URL(string: "http://www.example.com/")) // optional 
vc.setInitialText("Initial text here.")
self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Thank you but it didn't work for me. Also, SLServiceTypeFacebook was deprecated in iOS 11.0.